# Row Grouping in datatables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have been trying to follow this approach of row grouping described in the following link.  http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

However while implementing the drawCallback function I had to change the name to "fnDrawCallback" for my datatable to recognize this function and also declare var api as   var api = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes( settings );  instead of the way described in the example (var api = this.api();) as otherwise I was getting an error. However now I am still getting a similar error while defining the rest of function if I follow the syntax and keywords given in the example. That is ,

```
var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;
             api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );
```

The error I get is "undefined is not a function " for the drawCallback function. I tried a lot trying to find a different way of writing the same function but I cannot understand why this doesn't work and why I had to change the api declaration too.

I am very new to this , so if someone could explain what the correct format would be to write this function without this error I would really appreciate it !

Please find my Jquery part listed below. Thanks in advance !!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oTable = $("#tableTenants").dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,

        "sAjaxSource": "/api/alltenantstatistic.json?iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=${totalCount}&sSortDir_0=asc",
        "aoColumns": [

                      { "mDataProp": "state","sClass": "student_rows" , "sWidth":"1%" },
                      { "mDataProp": "name","sClass": "student_rows" , "sWidth":"20%"},
                      { "mDataProp": "testAdmin","sClass": "student_rows" , "sWidth":"70%"},
                      { "mDataProp": "totalStudentCount","sClass": "select_rows" , "sWidth":"2%", "bSortable": false },
                      { "mDataProp": "totalPnPStudentCount","sClass": "select_rows" , "sWidth":"2%", "bSortable": false }
                     ],

        "aoColumnDefs": [
                        {   "fnRender": function(oObj) {
                                  return '<a href="#">' + oObj.aData.state + '</a>';

                                 },
                            "bUseRendered": false,
                            "aTargets": [0]
                         },
                        {   
                            "aTargets": [1],
                             "bVisible": false
                        },
                            ],                  
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
                         "fnDrawCallback": function ( settings ) {
                             console.log("hello");
                             var api = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes( settings ); // Had to change this from this.api();
                             var rows = api.rows({page:'current'}).nodes(); // Giving an error 
                                                         var last=null;
                                                          api.column(1, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                                                          if ( last !== group ) {
                                                                  $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                                                                     '<tr class="group"><td colspan="4">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                                                           );

                    last = group;
                }
            } );

                         }, 
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        //"bStateSave": true,
                        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span5'l><'span7'f><'span2'>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",

                        "sPaginationType":  "bootstrap",
                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                            "sEmptyTable": "No Organization Uploads available for this Tenant",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "",
                            "sProcessing": "Loading..."
                        }
    });
```

Comment: Any help Will be really appreciated !!! I am kind of stuck !

Comment: What is your datatable version? You need 1.10

Answer (score 1):

Its due to jquery datatable version problem. use below libraries and code

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>


"drawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var last = null;
                api.column(1, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="3">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );
                        last = group;
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: How can I use this approach if my td hava an (a tag)  inside it?
my row as <td><a></a></td>

Comment: Do you want to give a link to group row as well or only rows below the grouped row?

Comment: No, I don't want to give a link to group, just to grouping rows that which have links inside them.

Comment: so that logic you can give while rendering a row. This logic is for making only groups.

"aoColumns": [
               {
                    "mDataProp": "Name", "sClass": "center",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<a title="View Details" class="text-info" href="@StaticHelper.HostingEnvironment/Registration/Participant/Edit1/' + full.Id + '">' + full.Name + '</a>';
                    }
                ]